# openpyxl load_workbook ValueError: Table with name Table1 already exists

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

So I try to load an existing excel file with `openpyxl` using `load_workbook` and get the following error:

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/envs/tf-2-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/envs/tf-2-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 280, in read
    self.read_worksheets()
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/envs/tf-2-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.py", line 251, in read_worksheets
    ws.add_table(table)
  File "/home/barrachina/anaconda3/envs/tf-2-cpu/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py", line 571, in add_table
    raise ValueError("Table with name {0} already exists".format(table.name))
ValueError: Table with name Table1 already exists
```

This happens with version `3.0.5` but didn't happen with `3.0.3`.

1. How can I open it? I believe I should somehow open the file and delete one table definition (which according to the message I have at least two).
2. (For developers): I don't like the error. Offer a solution would be better or just a warning. Microsoft Office and Open office do open the file...

Comment: What does the excel file look like when opened in MS Excel? What do you see when you click on the small arrow in the upper left corner with the name of the current selected cell? (You should see names of all tables in the file.)

Comment: @druskacik I am on a Linux computer now. I checked how to do what you say on writer (open office) but failed. Tomorrow I'll be in another office I have with Windows. I've just emailed me the excel file there. For confidentiality reasons, I cannot upload it here. I'll have the response tomorrow. Thank you for your patiance.

Answer (score 1):

Writer from open office opens it without a problem, however, MS Excel has the following message:

[image]

After opening the file with Excel, saving it and closing it, it started working. However, I would have liked a solution without having to use Excel.
Furthermore, this document was fully generated with `openpyxl 3.0.2` so it should have been prevented to create a Table with the same name twice.