# How to convert multiple excel files to CSV utf-8 encoding using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, csv, encoding

I have 30+ `xlsx` files in same directory and using  `python` I would like to convert all files to csv with utf-8 encoding, regardless of whatever encoding is present in the file. I am using python's magic library to get the file names (below code).For conversion, I tried  the code mention by SO user Julian [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding) (I used the code posted [here](https://gist.github.com/julianthome/2d8546e7bed869079ab0f409ae0faa87)), but the code is throwing an error saying `"InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm`. Below is the code that is throwing an error.The second issue is based on my limited `python` knowledge I believe code will work for one excel file. How should I make it work for multiple files ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
# import a library to detect encodings
import magic
import glob

print("File".ljust(45), "Encoding")
for filename in glob.glob('path*.xlsx'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as rawdata:
        result = magic.from_buffer(rawdata.read(2048))
    print(filename.ljust(45), result)
```

**Code throwing error from SO User github link mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding)**

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    import csv
    from os import sys
    
    def get_all_sheets(excel_file):
        sheets = []
        workbook = load_workbook(excel_file,read_only=True,data_only=True)
        all_worksheets = workbook.get_sheet_names()
        for worksheet_name in all_worksheets:
            sheets.append(worksheet_name)
        return sheets
    
    def csv_from_excel(excel_file, sheets):
        workbook = load_workbook(excel_file,data_only=True)
        for worksheet_name in sheets:
            print("Export " + worksheet_name + " ...")
    
            try:
                worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)
            except KeyError:
                print("Could not find " + worksheet_name)
                sys.exit(1)
    
            your_csv_file = open(''.join([worksheet_name,'.csv']), 'wb')
            wr = csv.writer(your_csv_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
            for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
                lrow = []
                for cell in row:
                    lrow.append(cell.value)
                wr.writerow(lrow)
            print(" ... done")
            your_csv_file.close()
    
    if not 2 <= len(sys.argv) <= 3:
        print("Call with " + sys.argv[0] + " <xlxs file> [comma separated list of sheets to export]")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        sheets = []
        if len(sys.argv) == 3:
            sheets = list(sys.argv[2].split(','))
        else:
            sheets = get_all_sheets(sys.argv[1])
        assert(sheets != None and len(sheets

) > 0)
    csv_from_excel(sys.argv[1], sheets)
```

Comment: The header of your question contradicts the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first, the first error is obvious:
`InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support  file format, please check you can open it with Excel first.`

Does Excel successfully open this file? If yes, we need the workbook (or small part of it).

The answer to the second question:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vi:ts=4:et

"""I test to open multiple files."""
import csv
from pathlib import Path

from openpyxl import load_workbook

# find all *.xlsx files into current directory
# and iterate over it
for file in Path('.').glob('*.xlsx'):
    # read the Excel file
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    # small test (optional)
    print(file, wb.active.title)
    # export all sheets to CSV
    for sheetname in wb.sheetnames:
        # Write to utf-8 encoded file with BOM signature
        with open(f'{file.stem}-{sheetname}.csv', 'w',
                  encoding="utf-8-sig") as csvfile:
            # Write to CSV
            spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
            # Iterate over rows in sheet
            for row in wb[sheetname].rows:
                # Write a row
                spamwriter.writerow([cell.value for cell in row])
```

Also you can explicitly specify the [dialect of csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv-fmt-params) as [csv.writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv) parameter.

Comment: Receiving an error that says "ValueError: Table with name Data already exists" I checked using python-magic and file encoding is Microsoft Excel 2007+

Comment: I understand nothing. Where you got this error?

Comment: Sorry..at line  wb = load_workbook(file)

Comment: OK. Does Excel successfully open the file?

Comment: yes, it does...

Comment: After opening the file with Excel, saving it and closing it, it started working. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63615515/openpyxl-load-workbook-valueerror-table-with-name-table1-already-exists)

Comment: Thank you I was reading the same page as well! How to proceed with CSV utf-8 conversion ? TIA

Comment: What is TIA? In first, how many sheets in Excel workbook?

Comment: TIA= Thanks in Advance! There are approx 30 excel workbooks out of which 28 workbooks contains single sheets, and 2 workbook contains multiple sheets (10 sheets/workbook).

Comment: Oh, thanks for explanation. Well, does all of ten sheets need to save into one file?

Comment: 10 sheets will be in separate csv files with utf-8 encoding. The file name for will be the sheet names

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to use `Pandas` library? You can store all the files in a list using `os`. You can then loop through the list and open each `Excel` file using `read_excel` and then write to a `csv`. So it will look something like this:

```
"""Code to read excel workbooks and output each sheet as a csv""" 
""""with utf-8 encoding"""
#Declare a file path where you will store all your excel workbook. You 
#can update the file path for the ExcelPath variable
#Declare a file path where you will store all your csv output. You can 
#update the file path for the CsvPath variable

import pandas as pd
import os

ExcelPath = "C:/ExcelPath" #Store path for your excel workbooks
CsvPath = "C:/CsvPath" #Store path for you csv outputs

fileList = [f for f in os.listdir(ExcelPath)]

for file in fileList:
    xls = pd.ExcelFile(ExcelPath+'/'+file)
    sheets = xls.sheet_names #Get the names of each and loop to create 
                              #individual csv files 
    for sheet in sheets:
        fileNameCSV = str(file)[:-5]+'.'+str(sheet) #declare the csv 
                      #filename which will be excelWorkbook + SheetName
        df = pd.read_excel(ExcelPath+'/'+file, sheet_name = sheet)
        os.chdir(CsvPath)
        df.to_csv("{}.csv".format(fileNameCSV), encoding="utf-8")
```

Not the best but should meet your needs

Comment: Hi Nabeel, Thank you and welcome to SO. I tried above code and was curious about sheet_name=someSheetName. What will be the name Sheet, as we are reading files from directory ?

Comment: It will be the sheet name (or tab name) from the excel file. I assumed it will be the same and in all your excel sheets.  By default excel has `Sheet1` as the default name. If you have different sheets in each workbook - you can store the name of each sheet and then for each excel file you can loop through each sheet

Comment: Could you please share the code where each excel has different sheet name ? As I also mentioned in my above comments to Sergey Zaykov. I have 2 excel with multiple sheets. How would the above code work in that scenario ? I would like to use Pandas if it is doable for multiple sheets.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding but I have updated my original code to meet your needs

Comment: Sorry unfortunately cannot see updated code. Was the code updated to your previous post only ?

Comment: Sorry  - try now :)

Comment: New to SO so editting the code part to make sure is correct is time consuming

Comment: No problem.I understand.. Will take a look at updated code. Thank you very much for your time and efforts!

Comment: No worries - if you have additional question feel free to reach out :)

Comment: Thank you! I tried above suggested code and was receiving an error saying XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supportedSo I had to use engine='openpyxl' in pd.ExcelFile and pd.read_excel....  thanks again :)

Comment: phew!! glad you were able to solve it... good luck and continue coding